# SharpSvn GetInfo LastChangeRevision is wrong

Tags: c#, .net, svn, sharpsvn

I have the following code (testing in a .NET console application):

```
var client = new SvnClient();
var previousRevisionUri = new SvnUriTarget("https://approvaltests.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/approvaltests/trunk/projects/ApprovalTests/DotNetApprovals/ApprovalUtilities/CallStack/Caller.cs", 480);
SvnInfoEventArgs previousRevisionInfo;
client.GetInfo(previousRevisionUri, out previousRevisionInfo);
Console.WriteLine(previousRevisionInfo.LastChangeRevision);
```

How come I get 337 output from `previousRevisionInfo.LastChangeRevision`, when we can see here: http://approvaltests.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/approvaltests/trunk/projects/ApprovalTests/DotNetApprovals/ApprovalUtilities/CallStack/Caller.cs?view=log
that the previous revision was 384..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In revision 384 the parent directory was changed, but the file itself was not.

ViewVC shows this as a change of history on the node, while the node itself was not changed.

Looking at r384:

```
Directory: trunk/projects/ApprovalTests/DotNetApprovals/ApprovalUtilities/ added
(Copied from trunk/projects/ApprovalTests/DotNetApprovals/SimpleLogger, r383)

Directory: trunk/projects/ApprovalTests/DotNetApprovals/SimpleLogger/  deleted
```

See http://approvaltests.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/approvaltests?view=revision&revision=384